# how to call default method in interface use reflection

Tags: java-8

```
public interface TestServiceIface {
    default String test(String str, int flag) {
        return str;
    }
}
```

interface like this,if implements the interface, and have an instance ,how can I call default method? if use reflection, how to do?
And I only have this interface,no Impl class and no Impl instance.how to call the default method?

Comment: Using reflection on the Class of your instance, e.g. `instance.getClass().getMethod("test")` doesn't work?

Comment: What's your effort?

Comment: You can invoke the method like any other method, unless overridden. If the method has been overridden, there is no official way to bypass the overriding method, which is also like any other method.

Answer (score 4):

Or via a `MethodHandle`, but do notice that you actually need an implementation class of that interface:

```
static class Impl implements TestServiceIface {

}
```

And the usage:

```
    MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(String.class, String.class, int.class);
    MethodHandle handle = MethodHandles.lookup().findVirtual(TestServiceIface.class, "test", methodType);

    String result = (String) handle.invoke(new Impl(), "test", 12);
    System.out.println(result); // test
```

Comment: if I have not an implementation class of that interface, can do that?

Comment: Also, in case the default method is overridden and you want to access the original (default) implementation, you can locate the appropriate `MethodHandle` via `findSpecial(`...`)` instead of `findVirtual(`...`)`

Comment: @raner good point.

Answer (score 2):

You can access interface *default methods* by reflection as below:

```
Class<TestServiceIface> type = TestServiceIface.class;

Method defaultMethod = type.getMethod("test", String.class, int.class);

String result = (String) defaultMethod.invoke(instance, "foo", 0);
```

However, if the subclass override the *default method*, then the overrided method will be called, which means interface default method also supports *polymorphism*.

Comment: where is your instance coming from ? Thats the key point, if I wanted to iterate over instance type, easy peasy but this is for interface only